# Autoforward email from specific folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to create autoforward email in vba with condition :

1. Only mail from "sourcemail@gmail.com" and there is "ABCDE" in the body
2. Only mail from specific folder under inbox \ownmail@gmail.com\Inbox\Folder1

Condition 1 is no problem if mail is coming to "inbox", but condition 2 if it's coming into "Folder1" it's not autoforwarded.

My code is like this:

```
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem

    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item

       'If it is a specific new email
       If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "sourcemail@gmail.com") And InStr(Item.Body, "ABCDE") > 0 Then

           Set objForward = objMail.Forward
           'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients
           With objForward
                .Subject = "test subject"
                .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>test body</BODY></HTML>" & objForward.HTMLBody
                .Recipients.Add ("recepient1@gmail.com")
                .Recipients.Add("recepient2@gmail.com").Type = olCC
                .Recipients.ResolveAll
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Send
           End With
       End If
    End If 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are only checking for mail that gets directly to your inbox. To check if a mail that gets in **Folder1** get forwarded, I think you have to do some similar as you did for your inbox, like this code:

```
' Inbox: Folder1
Public WithEvents InboxFolder1 As Outlook.Items

' Put this line in Sub Application_Startup. Correct the path if it's not this.
Set InboxFolder1 = objInbox.Folders.Item("ownmail@gmail.com").Folders.Item("Inbox").Folders.Item("Folder1").Items

' Create this procedure
Private Sub InboxFolder1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' Put your code in here
    Debug.Print Item.Subject
End Sub
```